# Getting entities to collide with floor in RealityKit on visionOS

Tags: swift, realitykit, visionos

In RealityKit, building for visionOS, I'm trying to get an entity with a physics body to freewill and then collide (stopping movement, maybe with a small bounce). I want it to collide with the floor, eventually tables and couches too but can't figure out what I need to do. This is  my Swift code:

```swift
struct ImmersiveView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Immersive", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
                
                // setup sphere
                
                let sphere = scene.findEntity(named: "Sphere_Left")
                let physics = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default,
                                                   material: .default,
                                                   mode: .dynamic)
                
                sphere?.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                sphere?.components.set(physics)
                
                // steup floor
                
                let floorPhysics = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default,
                                                        material: .default,
                                                        mode: .static)
                
                let anchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: .floor, minimumBounds: [0.5, 0.5]))
                
                anchor.components.set(floorPhysics)
                anchor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                
                // add stuff
                
                content.add(scene)
                content.add(anchor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A point in the right direction and/or sample code would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

ב"ה

To address the challenge in your RealityKit setup for visionOS, where an entity with a physics body (like a sphere) is required to move freely and then collide with objects in the environment, including the floor and potentially other objects like tables and couches, we need to focus on two key components: the physics body settings of the entities and the collision detection setup. Here's a detailed breakdown and the revised code:

#### Understanding the Issue:

1. **Physics Body Component**: This component defines how an entity behaves in a physics simulation. It requires careful adjustment of properties such as mass, material, and mode (dynamic or static).
2. **Collision Shapes**: They determine how entities collide with each other. Accurate collision shapes are crucial for realistic interactions.
3. **Material Properties**: These influence how objects interact upon collision, affecting factors like bounce (restitution) and friction.

#### Resolving the Issue:

1. **Enhancing Sphere Physics**: The sphere is set to a dynamic mode, which is correct for a freely moving object. However, adjusting its material properties (restitution for bounce and friction for surface interaction) is crucial.
2. **Floor and Obstacle Setup**: The floor is static, which is appropriate. The same physics setup should apply to other static objects like tables and couches. Each should have a PhysicsBodyComponent with mode set to `.static` and collision shapes generated.
3. **Collision Detection**: Ensure all entities (the sphere, floor, tables, couches) have collision shapes that match their geometry for accurate collision detection.

#### Revised Swift Code:

```swift
import RealityKit
import ARKit

struct ImmersiveView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            if let scene = try? await Entity.load(named: "Immersive", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
                
                // Setup sphere with dynamic physics
                if let sphere = scene.findEntity(named: "Sphere_Left") {
                    let spherePhysics = PhysicsBodyComponent(
                        massProperties: .default,
                        material: .generate(friction: 0.5, restitution: 0.3),
                        mode: .dynamic)
                    
                    sphere.components.set(spherePhysics)
                    sphere.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                }
                
                // Setup floor with static physics
                let floor = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 2, depth: 2))
                let floorPhysics = PhysicsBodyComponent(
                    massProperties: .default,
                    material: .generate(friction: 0.8, restitution: 0.1),
                    mode: .static)
                
                floor.components.set(floorPhysics)
                floor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                
                // Anchor for the floor
                let anchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: .floor, minimumBounds: [0.5, 0.5]))
                anchor.addChild(floor)
                
                // Add entities to the scene
                content.add(scene)
                content.add(anchor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this revised code, the physics and collision properties are more finely tuned for realistic interactions. The sphere should now move freely and collide with the floor and other static objects, exhibiting a natural bounce and stopping upon impact.

For more complex geometries like tables and couches, ensure that their collision shapes accurately reflect their physical forms for correct collision detection and realistic physical interactions.

Comment: Good stuff! Thank you for this post!